# Where should I write `node.default` variable in chef repository?

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, berksfile

I want to use `[chef-rbenv][1]` cookbook.

I created a `Berksfile` in a chef-repo top directory like this:

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"
cookbook 'rbenv'
```

And installed cookbook by `berks vendor cookbooks`.

Then I added a `"recipe[rbenv::user]"` to server config json file.

According to the document I must set a variable `node.default['rbenv']['user_installs']` to install rbenv. But I couldn't figure out where I should write it.

Can anyone show me where and how should I write the variable?

**My Environments (Edit)

I'm using `local mode` like this:

```
$ sudo chef-client --local-mode -c solo.rb -j localhost.json
```

### solo.rb

```
base = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
file_cache_path "/tmp/chef-solo"
cookbook_path ["#{base}/site-cookbooks", "#{base}/cookbooks"]
role_path "#{base}/roles"
```

### localhost.json

```
{
    "run_list" : [
    "recipe[rbenv::user]"
    ]
}
```

### Berksfile

```
source "https://api.berkshelf.com"

cookbook 'rbenv'
```

### roles/rbenv.rb

```
name "rbenv"

default_attributes({
                       'rbenv' => {
                           'user_installs' => {
                               'user'    => 'ironsand',
                               'rubies'  => ['1.9.3-p0'],
                               'global'  => '1.9.3-p0',
                           }
                       },
                   })
```

And this is the error when I run the command:

```
Starting Chef Client, version 11.14.6
[2014-09-18T03:56:08+09:00] WARN: Child with name 'vm-mint.json' found in multiple directories: /home/ironsand/my_chef_repo/nodes/vm-mint.json and /home/ironsand/my_chef_repo/nodes/vm-mint.json
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["rbenv::user"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - git
  - rbenv
  - dmg
  - yum-epel
  - build-essential
  - apt
  - windows
  - runit
  - ohai
  - yum
  - chef_handler
Compiling Cookbooks...

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe user for cookbook rbenv


Running handlers:
[2014-09-18T03:56:10+09:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2014-09-18T03:56:10+09:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-09-18T03:56:10+09:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 3.019030351 seconds
[2014-09-18T03:56:10+09:00] ERROR: could not find recipe user for cookbook rbenv
[2014-09-18T03:56:10+09:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would put this in a role or wrapper cookbook. If you are unfamiliar with Chef, a role is probably easiest:

```
default_attributes({
  'rbenv' => {
    'user_installs' => whatever,
  },
})
```

Comment: Maybe can you tell me how to write a role? I struggled already hours about this problem, I even read again chef's book. But I'm still stuck with this.

Comment: I think that goes a bit beyond what I can fit on here. Chef Software and many other places (myself included) offer Chef training, might want to start there. learnchef.com is also a place to start, though I'm not as much of a fan as I once was.